# REST API - Different Behaviour on Different Servers

Tags: php, debugging

We have created a REST API PHP setup which is designed to compare the Tables of one database with another and if the user doesn't exist in one, create it in the Application. Also if there is a change to a user i.e. Email address, string etc then update it.

We've had a script created which using php works fantastically on our test server, it creates a user when required and updates them when required.

When we move this over to a different server which has the same database structure, same tables, same root username and password etc, it isn't recognising the existing users. It thinks it has xx,xxx users to create and then fails as 'user with that username already exists'.

Does any one have any ideas why this maybe the case? Below is the main php file which then has a config file, a db.php, a common.php and then a GpsGateapi.php

```
require_once('rest_api_includes/Config.php');
require_once(Config::API_INCLUDES_DIR . '/DB.php');
require_once(Config::API_INCLUDES_DIR . '/Gpsgate_API.php');
require_once(Config::API_INCLUDES_DIR . '/Common.php');

class API_Sync
{
    /** @var int application id */
    private $application_id;

    /** @var int user type id */
    private $user_type_id;

    /** @var Gpsgate_API instance */
    private $api;

    /** @var DB instance */
    private $db;

    /** @var string<show|log> Show or log errors */
    private $errors_report_type;

    /** @var string<show|log|none> Show or log actions */
    private $actions_report_type;

    /**
     * Sets variables, connects to database and REST API
     * 
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->application_id = Config::API_APPLIATION_ID;
        $this->user_type_id = Config::API_USER_TYPE_ID;
        $this->errors_report_type = Config::API_SHOW_OUTPUT ? 'show' : 'log';
        $this->actions_report_type = Config::API_SHOW_OUTPUT ? 'show' : (Config::API_ACTIONS_LOGGING ? 'log' : 'none');
    }

    /**
     * Main method that controlls all the process
     * 
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->prepare();          

        $gpsgate_users_result = $this->api->getUsers();

        if ($gpsgate_users_result->status !== 200) {
            throw new Exception(implode('; ', $gpsgate_users_result->body));
        }

        $gpsgate_users = $gpsgate_users_result->body;
        $db_users = $this->db->get(DB::TBL_PERSONS);

        $res = $this->compare($gpsgate_users, $db_users);

        $this->updateUsers($res['update']);
        $this->createUsers($res['create']);
    }

    /**
     * Create gsgate users data from database array
     * 
     * @param array $users
     */
    private function createUsers($users)
    {
        if (!empty($users)) {
            $this->logOrShowAction("Begin to create users data.");

            foreach ($users as $user) {
                $res = $this->api->createUser([
                    'email'         => $user['Email'],
                    'name'          => $user['FirstName'],
                    'surname'       => $user['LastName'],
                    'driverID'      => $user['RFID'],
                    'username'      => $user['UserName'],
                    'password'      => Common::generatePassword(),
                    'userTypeId'    => $this->user_type_id,
                    'description'   => $user['Location'],
                ]);

                if ($res->status !== 200) {
                    throw new Exception($res->body);
                }
            }

            $this->logOrShowAction("Done.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update gsgate users data from database array
     * 
     * @param array $users
     */
    private function updateUsers($users)
    {
        if (!empty($users)) {
            $this->logOrShowAction("Begin to update users data.");

            foreach ($users as $user) {
                $res = $this->api->updateUser([
                    'email'     => $user['Email'],
                    'name'      => $user['FirstName'],
                    'surname'   => $user['LastName'],
                    'driverID'  => $user['RFID'],
                    'description'  => $user['Location'],
                ], $user['gpsgate_id']);

                if ($res->status !== 200) {
                    throw new Exception($res->body);
                }
            }
            
            $this->logOrShowAction("Done.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Compare arrays and return list of users data to update/create
     */
    private function compare($gpsgate_users, $db_users)
    {
        $this->logOrShowAction("Begin to compare users data.");

        $gpsgate_user_key = 'username';
        $db_user_key = 'UserName';
        $gpsgate_users = Common::setIndexesByKey($gpsgate_user_key, $gpsgate_users);

        $res = [
            'update' => [],
            'create' => [],
        ];

        foreach ($db_users as $user) {
            $user_key = $user[$db_user_key];

            if (!empty($gpsgate_users[$user_key])) {
                if ($this->userInfoVary($gpsgate_users[$user_key], $user)) {
                    $user['gpsgate_id'] = $gpsgate_users[$user_key]->id; // add gpsgate id
                    $res['update'][] = $user;
                }

            } else {
                $res['create'][] = $user;
            }
        }

        $this->logOrShowAction('Done');
        $this->logOrShowAction('Need to create: ' . count($res['create']) . ' rows; to update: ' . count($res['update']) . ' rows.');

        return $res;
    }

    /**
     * Check is the information between db user and api user is different
     */
    private function userInfoVary($gpsgate_user, $db_user)
    {
        return $db_user['Email'] != $gpsgate_user->email
            || $db_user['FirstName'] != $gpsgate_user->name
            || $db_user['LastName'] != $gpsgate_user->surname
            || $db_user['RFID'] != ($gpsgate_user->driverID ?? '')
            || $db_user['Location'] != $gpsgate_user->description;
    }

    /**
     * Connects to database, REST API, creates folders for errors and actions if need
     */
    private function prepare()
    {
        if ($this->errors_report_type == 'log') {
            if (!file_exists(dirname(Config::API_LOG_FILE_ERRORS))) {
                mkdir(dirname(Config::API_LOG_FILE_ERRORS));
            }
            if (!file_exists(Config::API_LOG_FILE_ERRORS)) {
                file_put_contents(Config::API_LOG_FILE_ERRORS, '');
            }
        }
        if ($this->actions_report_type == 'log') {
            if (!file_exists(dirname(Config::API_LOG_FILE_ACTIONS))) {
                mkdir(dirname(Config::API_LOG_FILE_ACTIONS));
            }
            if (!file_exists(Config::API_LOG_FILE_ACTIONS)) {
                file_put_contents(Config::API_LOG_FILE_ACTIONS, '');
            }
        }

        $this->logOrShowAction('Trying to connect to database and GPSGATE REST API.');

        $this->api = new Gpsgate_API(Config::API_APPLIATION_ID, Config::API_USER_TYPE_ID);
        $this->db = DB::instance();

        $this->logOrShowAction('Done.');
    }

    /**
     * Logs error message in file or output in browser
     * 
     * @param string $msg
     */
    public function logOrShowError($msg)
    {
        $msg = "<span style='color: red; font-weight: 600;'>Error: " . $msg . "</span>";
        $this->writeOrEchoMessage($msg, Config::API_LOG_FILE_ERRORS, $this->errors_report_type);
    }

    /**
     * Logs action message in file or output in browser
     * 
     * @param string $msg
     */
    public function logOrShowAction($msg)
    {
        $this->writeOrEchoMessage($msg, Config::API_LOG_FILE_ACTIONS, $this->actions_report_type);
    }

    private function writeOrEchoMessage($msg, $file, $report_type)
    {
        if ($report_type == 'none') {
            return ;
        }

        $msg = '[' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '] ' . $msg;

        if ($report_type == 'show') {
            echo $msg . '<br>';

        } else {
            $h = fopen($file, 'a+');
            fwrite($h, strip_tags($msg) . PHP_EOL);  
            fclose($h);
        }
    }
}


$sync = new API_Sync();

try {
    $sync->run();

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $sync->logOrShowError($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: your code seems to be creating a log file of what it's doing. can you locate the log file? the path to the file is somewhere in the config.php file it seems.

Comment: My guess would be that `$db_user_key = 'UserName';` is wrong and you have a different column name, but it is impossible to say based on this info. It is weird to have a debugging question here. It is just testing different parts of code manually until you find which one is failing, or by better programmers writing unit or integration tests for the same. Even though it is a REST client, the question itself does not have anything to do with REST.